# Pure Javascript populate data to select options from JSON URL

Tags: javascript, html, json

I had a javascript function that pulls data from url, however im having "**undefined**" options when im trying to add it on the next select element.
 Here is my code.

**First Select element**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="font-bold no-margins">City/State *</label>
    <select name="city_state" class="form-control required" id="city_state"  onchange="populateSelect(this);">
        <?php
            echo '<option value="'.$city_state_data->id.'">'.$city_state_data->name.'</option>';
            foreach ($city_states as $city_state) {
                if($city_state_data->id != $city_state->id)
                {
                  echo '<option value="'.$city_state->id.'">'.$city_state->name.'';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </select>
  </div>
```

**Second Select element**

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="font-bold no-margins">Locale *</label>
    <select name="locale" class="form-control required" id="locale">
      <?php
        echo '<option value="'.$locale_data->id.'">'.$locale_data->name.'</option>';
          foreach ($locales as $locale) {
              if($locale_data->id != $locale->id){
                echo '<option value="'.$locale->id.'">'.$locale->name.'';
              }
          }
      ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Now my JS script**

```
<script>
function populateSelect(item) {
    // json url
    //var url = 'citystate/' + item.value + '/locales/';
var url = '[{"id":33,"name":"Boni Avenue"},{"id":34,"name":"Shaw Boulevard"}]';

    // empty select
    document.getElementById('locale').options.length = 0;

    var ele = document.getElementById('locale');
    for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
        // populate select element with json
        ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML +
            '<option value="' + url[i]['id'] + '">' + url[i]['name'] + '</option>';
    }
}
</script>
```

Can you please help me how can i fix this **undefined** values in the select box.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **parse your JSON** string if you want to access the data.

```
function populateSelect(item) {
    var url = '[{"id":33,"name":"Boni Avenue"},{"id":34,"name":"Shaw Boulevard"}]';
    var data = JSON.parse(url);
    // empty select
    document.getElementById('locale').options.length = 0;

    var ele = document.getElementById('locale');
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // populate select element with json
        ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML +
            '<option value="' + data[i]['id'] + '">' + data[i]['name'] + '</option>';
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for great HELP, however it still not working if im using the original url. http://127.0.0.1:8000/citystate/10/locales
which the values are the: [{"id":33,"name":"Boni Avenue"},{"id":34,"name":"Shaw Boulevard"}]

Comment: maybe is a problem with the async call, please add the code that gets the data from that url.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: You said that you're using the original url 127.0.0.1:8000/citystate/10/locales, how are you fetching the data from this url? are you using XMLHttpRequest or maybe jquery ajax?